# How to display default chrome history in Alfred?

Tags: macos, big-sur, automation, alfred

Alfred beginner here. I found [this awesome workflow](https://github.com/tupton/alfred-chrome-history) which enables chrome browser history **search** in alfred.

Is there a way to add default chrome browser history to it? I want to type `ch` and have the last 10 or so entries displayed instead of having to search for a keyword.

[image]

**`ch script filter`**:

```
PROFILE="~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default"
PATH="env/bin:$PATH"
python chrome.py "${PROFILE}" "{query}"
```

**`/bin/bash script`**:

```
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "{query}"
```

I don't want to post the whole **`chrome.py`** here, since I'm not the creator. It is available in the above link.